# How can I change white background for some text inputs on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

Yesterday I saw in a computer that some inputs backgrounds where blue instead of the default background (normally white) no matter what program or browser(ie text areas in browsers, writing space in Thunderbird, address bar in browsers, ...), so this must be some change in Windows system, but I cant find how.

I want to try it since I work with computer many hours a day, and changing the white will help.

How can I do this in Windows XP?

Comment: Tell us what you've tried that didn't work. Have you looked at system settings [display properties color schemes](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-xp/help/setup/personalize-windows-xp)?

Comment: @CharlieRB LOL, no problem!